# Creating In generic Function to read both csv & Parquet Files in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create a generic function in one of my Databricks notebook where i am passing fileType as a parameter of the function and in my other notebook when i am calling the function i am just declaring the fileType as 'csv' or 'parquet'. But this giving me error as following

An error occurred while calling o1437.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: fileType. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

My code to create the function looks like this:

```
def createBronzeDeltaTable(schemaExcelPath, schemaExcelTab ,sourceCsvPath,DestiNationDeltaFilePath,dataBaseLocationPath,delemeterType,databaseTable,dbColumnToOptimize,fileType):
   
    materialMasterDF_schema = spark.read.option("badRecordsPath",mountPoint+"/tmp/badRecordsPath").format(fileType).load(sourceCsvPath,header=True,schema=eval(create_schema(schemaExcelPath,schemaExcelTab)),sep=delemeterType)
    materialMasterDF_schema.printSchema()
    #materialMasterDF_schema.show()
    display(materialMasterDF_schema)
```

And when i am calling the function along with other parameters i am just defining the

```
fileType = "csv"/"parquet"
```

Can someone help me on this where it's getting wrong.

Comment: instead of passing format, why don't you pass simply the function ? `spark.read.csv` and `spark.read.parquet`

Comment: That's because i am doing it with a common function where the format is not specified. The format i will be passing as a parameter of that function

Comment: yes but your current parameter is a string. I'm offering you to use a function as a param.

Comment: I just tried with your solution


def createBronzeDeltaTable(schemaExcelPath, schemaExcelTab ,sourceCsvPath,DestiNationDeltaFilePath,dataBaseLocationPath,delemeterType,databaseTable,dbColumnToOptimize,fileType):
    materialMasterDF_schema = fileType(sourceCsvPath,header=True,schema=eval(create_schema(schemaExcelPath,schemaExcelTab)),sep=delemeterType)

this seems working fine but if i add .option() then it's throwing error that 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'option'

Comment: Are you adding .option after .csv or .parquet?

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi yes . 
materialMasterDF_schema = fileType(sourceCsvPath,header=True,schema=eval(create_schema(schemaExcelPath,schemaExcelTab)),sep=delemeterType).option("badRecordsPath",mountPoint+"/tmp/badRecordsPath")

fileType=spark.read.csv

Comment: Yeah it will fail in that case as spark.read.csv will return dataframe and not reader object , I will suggest that if only two (csv/parquet) are to be passed why not create if else with one function for csv other for parquet. and to add option in above case you can try materialMasterDF_schema = spark.read.option("badRecordsPath",mountPoint+"/tmp/badRecordsPath").fileType(sourceCsvPath,header=True,schema=eval(create_schema(schemaExcelPath,schemaExcelTab)),sep=delemeterType)  fileType=csv which I am not sure if will work